# Xpage Threads - cannot access other classes

Tags: java, multithreading, xpages

I have been looking at the example posted on OpenNTF - http://www.openntf.org/internal/home.nsf/project.xsp?action=openDocument&name=Threads%20and%20Jobs my issue is I can't seem to refer to another class which is outside of the main class which creates the initial Thread.

Heres the code I am attempting to use, based on the demo code (which works fine BTW) - I have tried different variations including trying to call the Broadcast class from within the inner class and as in this case from the outer class.  In all cases I get a ClassNotFoundException - NB the Broadcast class is in the same package as this ThreadSample.

```
public class ThreadSample {

private MyThread myThread;

public  boolean isRunning() {
    return myThread != null;
}

public  void startThread()
throws NotesException {
    if (myThread != null) {
        stopThread();
    }

    try {
        {
            if (myThread == null) {
                myThread = new MyThread();
                myThread.start();
            }
            System.out.println("Thread started");
        }
    } catch (Throwable t) {
        t.printStackTrace();
    }
}

public  void stopThread() {
    if (myThread != null) {
        synchronized (ThreadSample.class) {
            if (myThread != null) {
                myThread.stopRequest = true;
                myThread = null;
                System.out.println("   >> Thread stopping");
            }
        }
    }
}
public void test(){
    System.out.println("HERE in Test");
    Broadcast.test_subscribe();
}

class MyThread extends Thread {
    boolean stopRequest;
    private ThreadSessionExecutor<IStatus> executor;

    MyThread() throws NotesException {

        this.executor = new ThreadSessionExecutor<IStatus>() {
            @Override
            protected IStatus run(Session session) throws NotesException {
                try {
                    System.out.println("   >> Thread running here");
                    ThreadSample.this.test_subscribe();
                    System.out.println("   >> After test call");
                } catch (Throwable ex) {
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                }
                return Status.OK_STATUS;
            }
        };
    }

    public void run() {
        while (!stopRequest) {
            try {
                executor.run();
            } catch (Exception ex) {
            }
        }
        System.out.println("Thread left");
    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the Job is in the NSF, then it cannot access some core eclipse classes for security reasons. This is the case of the IStatus one, for example. On the other hand, if you deploy the class as part of a plug-in, then it can have a dependency on core eclipse runtime.
There is also a know issue with the context classloader in the ThreadSessionExecutor and it had been fixed in the next release of N/D.
With 8.5.3, it is better to have your jobs deployed as plug-ins.

Comment: Thanks Philippe I will try and deploy it as a plugin and see how it goes.

Comment: Do you have a link to creating and deploying a plugin which is not for a UIComponent - I looked at these tutorials here http://www-10.lotus.com/ldd/ddwiki.nsf/dx/Creating_an_XPages_Library but they are for a UI Component.

Is it the same for a pure code based plugin?

Comment: Check out the XSP starter kit: http://www.openntf.org/internal/home.nsf/project.xsp?action=openDocument&name=XSP%20Starter%20Kit

Answer (score 1):

If you need session access in a Thread, you can use SessionCloner. Then you don't need to deploy it as a plugin as it doesn't load it's own class loader. You might have to alter the java.policy file on the server (I modified the java.policy before testing this, so I'm not sure).

You need these imports:

> import com.ibm.domino.xsp.module.nsf.NSFComponentModule;
>
> import com.ibm.domino.xsp.module.nsf.NotesContext;
>
> import com.ibm.domino.xsp.module.nsf.SessionCloner;

The class needs two fields

> private SessionCloner sessionCloner;
>
> private NSFComponentModule module;

In the constructor:

> // Initialize objects that's needed to pass current session into
>
> this.module = NotesContext.getCurrent().getModule();
>
> this.sessionCloner = SessionCloner.getSessionCloner();

In the run method (move the code from the anonymous ThreadSessionExecutor class' run method to the run method in your Thread class):

> Session session = null;
>
> try {
>
> NotesContext context = new NotesContext( this.module );
>
> NotesContext.initThread( context );
>
> session = this.sessionCloner.getSession();
>
> // Your code
>
> } catch ( Throwable exception ) {
>
> // Error logging, print stack trace / etc
>
> } finally {
>
> NotesContext.termThread();
>
> try {
>
> ```
>   this.sessionCloner.recycle();
> ```
>
> } catch ( NotesException exception ) {}
>
> }

Comment: Thanks Tommy - I will try that out.

Comment: @Tommy do you have any idea is SessionCloner exist for SessionAsSigner object? Thanks!

Comment: ...ok, I think I found answer for my comment above. This is: SessionCloner.getDesignerSessionCloner(false|true).getSession()